# Yii2: call static method of module class from within module

Tags: php, yii2

I created a module that works just fine. From the controllers and views within the module I want to access a static translation method of the module called `t` that I created as well. 
According to [Yii's documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html#accessing-modules) I should be able to access the static method of the module class (named Module) with `Module::t()` but I get this only to work when I prepend the namespace like `\app\modules\commission\Module::t()`.

Is this a configuration issue that I have missed and have to modify or is this the only way to access the Module class using namespacing? I have searched the internet but could not find a similar question.

Comment: write at the top of the file
`use \app\modules\commission\Module;`

than you can use `Module::t()` directly

Comment: @mohit, I have already done that and it works fine, thanx. But I was hoping this was not necessary. If I want to switch later on to `\backend\modules\...` or `\console\modules\...` I have to change all filles within the module using the static function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [aliases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html#aliases) and define alias for your module in configuration parameter *aliases*:

```
'aliases' => [
    '@mymodule' => 'app\modules\commission\Module',
],
```

and then call your method like this:

`call_user_func([Yii::getAlias('@mymodule'), 't', $params]);`

not so elegant as `Module::t()` but gives you flexibility to change your module class which implement your custom `t()` method

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed not so elegant, and it is more or less the same approach as described in the documentation using `\Yii::$app->getModule('commission')::t()`

Comment: as another option you can add your own class autoloader, because yii2 relies on psr-4 standard for autoloading, so you must to use `use \app\modules\commission\Module` to get your class loaded